# Pattern.matches - searching an entire string vs a substring

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

My regular expression is working properly here: https://regexr.com/4j143

However, when I try to use it in Apex it is not working:

```
String regExp = '/\\s{1,}(ORDER BY)\\s{1,}(ID)(\\s{1,}(ASC)){0,1}(\\s{1,}(NULLS)\\s{1,}(LAST)){0,1}\\s{0,},/gi';
String input = 'SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY ID, INDUSTRY ASC';

System.debug(Pattern.matches(regExp, input));
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with Java's unfortunate implementation of `matches()` - it assumes the input is the entire string. You feed it a regex of `/\\s{1,}...{0,},/gi` hoping that `matches()` will return `true` if the pattern matches a part of the input string but the actual regex that gets executed is `/^\\s{1,}...{0,},$/gi`. That will not match your entire string because your string does not begin with one or more spaces.

Salesforce docs do [explain](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_regions.htm) this nuance:

> A Matcher object finds matches in a subset of its input string called
>   a region. The default region for a Matcher object is always the
>   entirety of the input string.

With default region being the entire string, you need to revise your regex by adding segments that match text at the beginning and end of the string (before ORDER BY and after ASC|NULLS|LAST). Here's a simplified, single-backslashed version of your regex with `matches()` returning true on the region as entire input string:

`(.*)\s+(ORDER BY)\s+(\w+,?\s+)+ASC`

If only a portion of your string should be considered "input", the `region()` function referenced in the doc above will be useful.

Comment: Calling `find` will return true if you match just a substring.